# insert form_dropdown data into mysql database in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, view, model, controller

I am new in codeigniter and trying to insert form_dropdown data into database, But i am unabl to insert selected option into database.

This is my model:

```
public function insertUser()
{  
        $data1 = array(
            'id'=>$this->input->post('id'),
            'full_name'=>$this->input->post('full_name'),
            'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
            'contact_no'=>$this->input->post('contact_no'),
            'role'=>$this->roles[0], 
            'status'=>$this->status[0]
        );
        $this->db->insert('users',$data1);
        $data2['user_id']=$this->db->insert_id();
        $data2 = array(
            'type_of_paper'=>$this->input->post('type_of_paper'),
            'deadline'=>$this->input->post('deadline'),
            'acadmic_level'=>$this->input->post('acadmic_level'),
            'quality'=>$this->input->post('quality'),
            'noofpage'=>$this->input->post('noofpage'),
            'subject_area'=>$this->input->post('subject_area')
        );            
        $this->db->insert('orders',$data2);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

This is my controller:

```
public function order()
{
    $data['title']='Order';
    $data['page']='order';
    $data['type_of_paper'] = $this->writer_model->getTypeOfPaper();
    $data['deadline'] = $this->writer_model->getDeadline();
    $data['prices'] = $this->writer_model->getPrice();
    $data['acadmic_level']=$this->writer_model->getAcadmicLevel();
    $data['quality']=$this->writer_model->getQuality();
    $data['subject_area']=$this->writer_model->getSubjectArea();
    $data['currencies']=$this->writer_model->getCurrency();

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('full_name', 'Full Name', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[50]|is_unique[users.full_name]',
    array(
            'required'      => 'You have not provided %s.',
            'is_unique'     => 'This %s already exists.'
    ));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',
    array(
            'required'      => 'You have not provided correct %s.',
            'is_unique'     => 'This %s already exists.'
    ));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact_no', 'Contact No', 'trim|required');    
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('type_of_paper', 'Type Of Paper', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('deadline', 'Deadline', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('acadmic_level', 'Acadmic Level', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('quality', 'Quality', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('noofpage', 'No Of Pages', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject_area', 'Subject Area', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
    {   
        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('navbar', $data);
        $this->load->view('order', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer', $data);
    }else
    {                
        if($this->user_model->isDuplicate($this->input->post('email')))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'User email already exists');
            redirect(site_url().'/home/login');
        }else
        {
            $config=array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => '',
                'smtp_pass' => '',
                'mailtype' => 'html' 
                );

            $clean = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post(NULL, TRUE));
            $id = $this->user_model->insertUser($clean); 
            $token = $this->user_model->insertToken($id);                                        

            $qstring = $this->base64url_encode($token);                      
            $url = site_url() . '/home/complete/token/' . $qstring;
            $link = $url; 


            $message = '';                     
            $message .= 'You have signed up with our website.
                         Please click here to verify your email address:'. $link;   

            $this->load->library('email',$config);
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->from('','Gourav shukla');
            $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
            $this->email->subject('This is an email Test');
            $this->email->message($message);
            $this->email->send();

            /*if($this->email->send();)
            {
                echo 'Your email was sent, fool.';
            }else
            {
                show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
            }                      

            echo $message; send this in email
            exit;*/


        };              
    }
}
```

This is my view code:

```
<?php // Change the css classes to suit your needs    
                    $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'order_form', 'name' => 'order_form');
                    echo form_open('/home/order', $attributes); ?>
                    <h3>Customer Information :</h3>
                    <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'full_name', 'id'=> 'full_name', 'placeholder'=>'Full Name', 'class'=>'full_name', 'value' => set_value('full_name'))); ?>
                    <?php echo form_error('full_name');?>
                    <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'email', 'id'=> 'email', 'placeholder'=>'Email', 'class'=>'email', 'value'=> set_value('email'))); ?>
                    <?php echo form_error('email');?>
                    <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'contact_no', 'id'=> 'contact_no', 'placeholder'=>'Contact No', 'class'=>'contact_no', 'value'=> set_value('contact_no'))); ?>
                    <?php echo form_error('contact_no');?>
                    <hr />
                    <h3>Order Pricing :</h3>
                    <?php $attributes = 'id="type_of_paper" class="form-control"';
                    echo form_dropdown('type_of_paper', $type_of_paper, set_value('type_of_paper'), $attributes);?>
                    <?php echo form_error('type_of_paper'); ?>
                    <?php $attributes = 'id="deadline" class="form-control"';
                    echo form_dropdown('deadline', $deadline, set_value('deadline'), $attributes); ?>
                    <?php echo form_error('deadline'); ?>
                    <select class="form-control" id="acadmic_level" name="acadmic_level" onchange="calculateTotal()">
                    <option value=""> - Acadmic Level - </option>
                    <?php foreach($acadmic_level as $row)
                    { 
                    echo '<option value="'.$row->value.'" id="'.$row->level_name.'">'.$row->level_name.'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    <?php echo form_error('acadmic_level'); ?>
                    <select class="form-control" name="quality" id="quality" onchange="calculateTotal()">
                    <option value=""> - Quality - </option>
                    <?php foreach($quality as $row)
                    { 
                    echo '<option value="'.$row->q_value.'" id="'.$row->q_type.'">'.$row->q_type.'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    <?php echo form_error('quality'); ?>
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" maxlength="150" name="noofpage" id="noofpage" placeholder="No Of Pages" onkeyup="calculateTotal()"/>
                    <?php $attributes = 'id="price" class="form-control"';
                    echo form_dropdown('prices', $prices, set_value('prices'), $attributes); ?>
                    <input id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="Amount in British Pound(£)" type="text" />
                    <?php echo form_error('noofpage'); ?>
                    <select class="form-control" name="currency" id="currency" onchange="getCurrency()">
                    <?php foreach($currencies as $row)
                    { 
                    echo '<option value="'.$row->rate.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    <?php echo form_error('currency'); ?><br />
                    <div id="finalPrice"></div><br />
                    <div id="totalPrice" name="totalPrice"></div>
                    <hr />
                    <h3>Order Information :</h3>
                    <select class="form-control" id="subject_area" name="subject_area">
                    <option value=""> - Subject Area - </option>
                    <?php foreach($subject_area as $row)
                    { 
                    echo '<option value="'.$row->subject_area.'">'.$row->subject_area.'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    <?php echo form_error('subject_area'); ?>
                    <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'required_topic', 'id'=> 'required_topic', 'placeholder'=>'Required Topic', 'class'=>'required_topic', 'value' => set_value('required_topic'))); ?>
                    <?php echo form_error('required_topic');?><br />
                    <?php echo "<input type='file' name='userfile' size='20' />"; ?><br />
                    <?php $data = array('name'=> 'vc_desc','id'=> 'vc_desc','value'=> set_value('vc_desc'),'rows'=> '6','cols'=> '10','placeholder'=>'Detailed Instructions','style'=> 'width:50%; margin-left:100px','class'=> 'form-control');
                    echo form_textarea($data); ?><br />
                    <hr />
                    <h3>Select Payment Method :</h3>
                    <?php echo form_radio("gender", "Female", NULL, set_radio('gender', 'Female')); ?>Female
                    <?php echo form_radio("gender", "Male", NULL, set_radio('gender', 'Male')); ?>Male<br />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="accept_terms_checkbox" value="Accept TOS" /> Accept Terms of Services<br>
                    <?php echo form_error('accept_terms_checkbox') ?>
                    <?php echo form_submit(array('value'=>'Place Order', 'class'=>'btn btn-md btn-primary btn-block')); ?>
                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

When i am running this code then i am getting this output:

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySzkV.png)

but i want to store option name into database not value from option.
Please fix this problem.
thanks in advance.

Comment: When you get the post data then get the all option name data also from database and then match the value of it and change the value in the post array.

Answer (score 0):

what i got from your last two lines and image that is data is inserting into database but values are inserting and you wants to insert names,

if i correct then,
you have to use your names in options value like

```
<option value="name">name or anything you want</option>
```

in form_dropdown

```
$style=array("id"=>"any_id","class"=>"any_class");
$dd_data=array();
$dd_data['']="-select-";
foreach($data as $row) // $data coming from server
{
$dd_data[$row['name']]=$row['name or anything'] // $row['name'] names that you wants to add into database
}
echo form_dropdown('field_name',$dd_data,'',$style);
```

this code is just an example it is not tested.